# "Inbox Zero" with Apple Watch Siri watchface and Activity?

Tags: apple-watch

I am a big fan of [Inbox Zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9UjeTMb3Yk) and any item left in my inbox means "I have yet to do this!"

The Siri watch face on my Apple Watch tends to follow this but there seems to always be one item left, no matter what I do, and this is the "Activity" item.

For example, today I went for a short bicycle ride. I'm not in the best shape so the short ride filled up my activity goal for today. I had already filled the "stand up" quota, I was close to my calories quota and the bicycle ride filled my exercise quota.

However, the Activity item is still there. I'd be the first to admit that is probably a "Good Thing™", considering the shape that I'm in, but it bugs me far more that I can't get "Inbox Zero", but rather "Inbox One-to-go".

Is there a way for me to say "When I've filled *all* the quotas I've set, please hide the Activity item"?

If this can (only) be done with watchOs 5, which is in beta, I would accept this as an answer, even though I'm on watchOs 4 (which would imply it isn't possible right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, with watchOS 4.3.1, it's not possible to remove Activity from the Siri watch face.

watchOS 5 is still in beta and there's been no indication from Apple that Activity can be removed, either.

Of course, Apple has in the past added and removed features while the software is in beta so this could change before it's officially released.